# jQuery table filter not quite sorting correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to use the following I found on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snLbLuu8/1/) (modified it a bit for this example). Not even sure if i'm posting this code correctly ... would be best to just look at the fiddle I guess.

```
{
    filters[col] = text;

    $(table).find('tr').each(function(i){
        $(this).data('passed', true);
    });

    for(index in filters)
    {
        if(filters[index] !== 'any')
        {
            $(table).find('tr td:nth-child('+index+')').each(function(i){
                if($(this).text().indexOf(filters[index]) > -1 && $(this).parent().data('passed'))
                {
                    $(this).parent().data('passed', true);
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).parent().data('passed', false);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $(table).find('tr').each(function(i){
        if(!$(this).data('passed'))
        {
            $(this).hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Basically I will have a table with, lets say, 100 rows, and each row will have a column with a timer value in it, e.g. 10 min or 15 min. When a user clicks the appropriate "custom filter" like 10 min, the table will be filtered to only show all entries with 10min. So far it works 100%.

But, when a user might filter anything with one digit, like 5 min or 1 min it throws out, well everything for example user filters by 5 min, now it throws out 5 min, 15 min, 45 min etc.

In the example the 10, 15, 45 and 59 min filters does their job correctly. The 5 and 9 min buttons filters wrong, you will see what i mean in the example.

Are there any way to remedy that situation, so that when 5 min filter is clicked it only loads table columns with the value 5 min? I have seen something similar in another fiddle (which i can't find right now) think it was called a regular expression and not a indexOf ... this was for a search function within a table but it worked.

Please let me know if you need more information or a better description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a much simpler approach that uses `filter()` and `eq()` and only loops the rows once

```
function apply_filter(table, col, text) {
  var $rows = $(table).find('tr');
  if (text === 'any') {
    $rows.show();
  } else {
    // hide all rows then filter the ones to show
    $rows.hide().filter(function() {
      return $(this).children().eq(col - 1).text().trim() === text;
    }).show();
  }
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/snLbLuu8/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you charlie exactly what i needed! Very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @charlietfl the above code works perfect as mentioned, but i have got to a point where there is too much filters. Say i wanted to group one filter to include 2 values e.g. when you click the button show all with '5 min' and 10 min' values rather then just '5 min'.

Comment: Modify logic in determining what gets returned inside filter(). Could create array of selections

Comment: Sadly i have less then a basic understanding of coding in general, the bits and pieces i have put together to try and make this work is laughable at best, can't even get an array working. I'll keep looking and trying. Thanks for advice.